# Should I prefer 'asking for permission' in this case?

Tags: python, exception, coding-style

Into my function I'm expecting an argument that may either be a `tuple` or a `str`. Being new to Python, I have learned that 'begging forgiveness' is better than 'asking for permission'. So instead of checking the type of the argument, I'm doing this:

```
def f(a):
    try:  # to handle as tuple
        e1, e2, e3 = a
        ...
    except ValueError:  # unpacking failed, so must be a string.
        pass
    # handle as string
```

However, this won't always work. What if `a` is a `str` of length `3`? The code would treat it as a tuple.

What should I do in this case? Resort to type checking? Is it less 'Pythonic'? Please explain the most 'Pythonic' solution and why it is so.

Comment: Are the arguments user input? There might be a better place to check the format than inside the function itself.

Comment: is it important, that you use the same function with two different argument types?

Comment: I would suggest using `isinstance()` instead of `type()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python

Comment: Use keyword arguments and accept two different parameters?

Comment: would you split the string to get a tuple eventually?

Comment: Function overloading by argument type is unpythonic. Better `def f_tuple` or `f_string` (of course, with more meaningful names).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has the `isinstance()` function for a reason. Sometimes checking the type of an argument is the right thing to do; it would be perfectly acceptable here.

Answer (score 2):

It’s perfectly fine to make type checks in Python, especially when you want to do this for the purpose of function overloading.

But I would suggest you to make a type check on the string, instead of the tuple. While it may seem like you would always pass a tuple, there are a lot of cases where passing a different sequence may make a lot of sense too, for example a list is perfectly fine too.

So you should leave the logic the way it is, but first check for a string input:

```
def f(a):
    if isinstance(a, str): # in Python 2, check against `basestring`
        # handle as string
        # …
    else:
        # handle as tuple
        e1, e2, e3 = a
        # …
```

That way you get a proper exception bubbled up in case when the unpacking does not succeed properly, for example if someone passes a 2-element tuple. In your original code, you would have to handle this yourself in some way (to avoid running the code that thinks it’s a string).

Answer (score 1):

Explicit is better than implicit: define two functions, one for tuples, the other for strings. The second best choice would be, to have one function with three arguments, two of them are optional:

```
def f(e1, e2=None, e3=None):
    if e2 is None and e3 is None:
        # a string
    else:
        # three strings
```

The least best possibility is to check the type of the argument:

```
def f(a):
    if isinstance(a, basestring):
        # a string
    else:
        # perhaps a tuple
```